# Is $L: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a linear operator? How is it a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How would I check if this is a linear operator with the additivity condition $L(u+v) = L(u)+L(v)$? Once I understand how to do the additivity I'm sure I can figure out the scalar multiplication.

If I were first to apply the left side of the condition $L(u+v)$ what would become of the matrix $x+y, y+2$. I feel like the $2$ is going to mess up one of the conditions.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: If you feel like something is going to mess up one of the conditions, that's a hint to switch your strategy and try proving that $L$ is *not* linear. So try looking for a counterexample: guess some numbers to plug into and contradict one of the linearity formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the $+2$ in the second coordinate will make it not linear. A linear map must satisfy $L(\textbf{0}) =\textbf{0}$ (here $\textbf{0} = (0,0)$), since by the preservation of scalar multiplication we would have $$L(\textbf{0}) = L(0\cdot \textbf{0}) = 0 L(\textbf{0}) = \textbf{0}.$$

However, with your example, $L(\textbf{0}) = (0,2) \neq \textbf{0}$.

Also, note that this is a map $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, not from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

$L(0,2)=(2,4)$

$2 L(0,1)=2(1,3)=(2,6)$